# OS X: Recovering from an incompatible screen resolution

Tags: macos, display, resolution

I clicked on a screen resolution in OS X that was incompatible with my monitor and/or monitor cable. I can restart with the shift key held down and boot into a usable resolution, but if I restart in "normal" mode, my display is useless. How can I recover from this?

Comment: By holding shift you are telling the OS to use a known good resolution.  You should be able to just change the resolution like you did the first time.  IS tehre something preventing you from doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After booting with Shift held down, go back into System Preferences and choose a known good resolution—that'll write it back to the PRAM.

Alternatively, you can just wipe the PRAM by starting up holding Command-Option-P-R until you hear TWO startup chimes.

Comment: It's amazing how often people just say "Zap the PRAM!" as the solution to any problem. However, in this case I have a feeling it would work.

Comment: @daviewales My confidence on this actually goes back to _System 7.5_, where we would try to fix a different problem by zapping the PRAM, and always end up messing up our screen resolution. :-)